# Visual Studio 2005 Annoyances

Tags: visual-studio-2005

There are a couple of things I find really annoying about Visual Studio.  Admittedly, I have a old version so these might be fixed in later versions.  I'm writing c++ stuff.  Anyway here they are:

1) Is there anyway to clear all breakpoints?  If I leave breakpoints set, they seem to multiply and get attached to adjacent lines as I add more code.  I then have to go in and clear them out one-by-one.

2) Is there anyway to make the text find work better?  If I want to find the next occurrence, I have to either do a `ctrl F` or an `EDIT FIND` followed by clicking `FIND NEXT` in the search box.  Is there some shortcut key for `FIND NEXT`?

TIA, Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used VS2005 but I remember the functionality was the same here as in VS2008.  Hope this helps.
1) To clear all break points you can do Ctrl Shift F9, or select it from the debug menu.
2) If you do Control F to find and then you can hit F3 to do Find Next.

Comment: Thanks a bunch to all who posted answers!  I have a really really old visual studio so some of the things mentioned don't even exist but the F3 and Ctrl shift F9 do work!

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Debug Menu and select Delete All Breakpoints (Not available in the Express version)
2. Maybe I've misunderstood what you're asking, but you could just hit enter to skip to the next match when the Find dialog is open.

Answer (score 1):

You can also customize which shortcut key you want for find next.

Go Tools-> Customize -> Keyboard -> Find "Edit.FindNext" and set the shortcut you would like.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+F9 to delete all breakpoints.
2. You can use F3 (or Ctrl+F3) to search for the currently-selected word without bringing up the Find And Replace window.

Answer (score 0):

If you do Find In Files, then the F8 key will move through the results. The same thing works for moving through errors/warnings when a build completes.